# Multivariate Appoximation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation, chebyshev-polynomials

I have a mathematical model for a complex system which I would like to approximate it. My idea is to run this complex model once and produce some outputs, and then fit a polynomial for these outputs. However, my model has several inputs and I can not use known smooth polynomials, e.g. Chebyshev, easily. On the other hand I also want to avoid solving an optimization problem to fit a polynomial to the outputs.

I have two questions:

1. Can you please let me any good reference for the approximation of multivariate functions?
2. How can I use Chebychev polynomials for the multivariate function?

Regards,
Reza

Comment: Does your model have a functional representation? Or, can it at least be evaluated on a regular grid? If so, then use tensor-product splines to interpolate. For scattered data use radial basis functions.